# Google Structured Data Testing Tool error "url: missing and required" for Microdata markup of logo

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to use Microdata to mark up my webpage. When I got to marking up the logo I am stuck, I keep getting the error "`url`: missing and required". Must I include a `url` when I am declaring `logo` as an item property?

Error in the Structured Data Testing Tool:

[image: screenshot of the Structured Data Testing Tool: 'url: missing and required']

Answer (score 1):

This error says that Google’s SDTT requires the `url` property for an `Organization` item.  The value would be the URL of the organization (typically the homepage), not the URL of the organization’s logo.

Note that "requires" does *not* mean that you must provide the `url` property to have valid Microdata + Schema.org (neither Schema.org nor Microdata require *any* properties). It’s only Google that requires it for showing something based on your markup in Google Search (e.g., a Rich Snippet, or a Knowledge Graph feature like  [Corporate Contacts](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/contact-points)). If you don’t provide it, Google probably doesn’t show it, but nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have organisation under organistaion. Remove Line 8 and 10.
you have a `<a><a>...</a></a>`